# Custom control generated from datatable

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a help with functionality where i have data in dataset table. 
For each row i need to create control with some data and all of this controls must be in flow layout. I want to make custom control from this, that can bind to datasource like dataset.

More info:
I have made my custom control

```
  [System.ComponentModel.ComplexBindingProperties("DataSource")]
        public partial class UserControl1 : System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
        {
            public object DataSource
            {
                get { return datatable; }
                set 
                { datatable = (List<String>)value; 
                  MakeControls(); 
                 }
            }

    private void MakeControls()
    {
        if (datatable == null)
            return;

        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.Controls.Clear();
        foreach(String str in datatable)
        {
            GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
            gb.Text = str;

            this.Controls.Add(gb);
        }
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }
        }
```

I dont know is this enough. So Datasource is only property with method that is fired when its set.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the rows in the dataset table, constructing a new control for each one, and add it to a FlowLayoutPanel on your form.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Textbox t = new TextBox(); //Or whatever control you want
    t.Text = dr.Value; // NB: Not actual code, I'm not at my IDE
    flowPanel.Controls.Add(t);
}
```